# Stop responsiveness of bootstrap on my site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi so for my website i have an issue with my code. When you make the page smaller all of the content on it adjust to the screen. How do i disable this effect? How do you make it so when the content hits the edge of the webpage it just stops. I believe the term is fixed? I have tried different ways to fix this but since i am new i do need a little help. I am using bootstrap.

My Site: http://rootforsite.azurewebsites.net/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Their site in the documentation has the instructions on how to do that. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Comment: you can remove media query to stop responsiveness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no time to read the document, just use [THIS](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css) css file along with bootstraps css file and change the padding,margin etc if you want.
Also remember to **remove** the block

```
/* Demonstrate the grids */
.col-xs-4 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you read the bootstrap docs here http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive it recommends the following to disable responsiveness.

Steps to disable page responsiveness

1. Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs
2. Override the width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after the default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all resolutions.